# Cannot access database containers due to timeout

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, owncloud

I am running a MariaDB container on a Synology NAS.
It worked fine before, but after installing traefik (and subsequently uninstalling it due to some unrelated problems) no container can access any database.
Additionally if I try to connect to the containers via Adminer or PHPMyAdmin a timeout error occurs.
Strangely when I connect to the container via HeidiSQL and a domain pointed to the NAS from my computer, i can access both.
My OwnCloud installation was affected as well with the owncloud/server container throwing a "Database didn't come up in time!" error.

When looking at logs of the MariaDB container, no error or warning appears.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"

services:
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - /volume1/docker/mariadb/phpmyadmin.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
        networks:
            - pma
        depends_on:
            - instance-1

    instance-1:
        image: mariadb:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: mariadb-instance-1
        env_file: /volume1/docker/mariadb/instance-1/mariadb.env
        ports:
            - "8081:3306"
        volumes:
            - /volume1/docker/mariadb/instance-1/data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /volume1/docker/mariadb/instance-1/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
        networks:
            - pma
            - mariadb_network

networks:
    pma:
    mariadb_network:
```

my.cnf

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
# !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
query-cache-type = ON
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 512M

[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

mariadb.env

```
TZ=UTC
MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=...
MARIADB_USER=...
MARIADB_PASSWORD=...
```

phpmyadmin.php

```
<?php

$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation'] = "utf8mb4_unicode_ci";
$cfg['FirstDayOfCalendar'] = 1;
$cfg["Console"]["Mode"] = "collapse";

$cfg['Servers'][1]['host'] = "mariadb-instance-1";
$cfg['Servers'][1]['port'] = "3306";
$cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type'] = "cookie";
```

I have tried reinstalling all container images and the Synology Container Manager itself, changing various config values, reverse proxy settings and firewall settings.

Comment: the host will be localhost.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? I have tried to access the database via phpmyadmin with  `mariadb-instance-1:3306` and `172.0.X.X:3306`

Comment: Any reason you're using multiple Docker networks?

Comment: yeah, i use the `pma` network for linking sql databases (like owncloud) to the singular phpmyadmin instance and `maria_network` ist for containers wishing to access `mariadb-instance-1`